# Multiple fields in Java POJO with same names but different type

Tags: java, mongodb, list, pojo

I am new to Java and started working with a startup as an intern. I am stuck in a situation where I want to use the same names for two different Java fields with different types.

For example:
I had an API contract wherein a field called `private String privateNews.`
Also, I have already stored some of the data with the above contract in the database.
Now I want to change it to a `private List<String> privateNews`  with keeping name same.
Replacing the current field is causing a serialization issue while fetching entries from the database (MongoDB).
I am thinking to keep both fields for some time and do the migration.

Is there a way I can use the same name with different types of fields in Java? or any other solution to deal with such problems?

Comment: You can't.  Use "fieldName1" and "fieldName2" or something, you literally have to use different names, there's no way around it.

Comment: No this cannot be done. In java all class members must have different names.

Comment: You do not want to have two members with the same name but different types.  In fact, you can't - that isn't how Java works.  You do not need to use the same data model for accessing the API and interacting with your storage.  The fact that the API has a single String and you want a List of Strings implies that you view the data differently than the API you are interacting with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.